# Mail looks different in outlook if sent via Outlook (Interop) or smtp

Tags: c#, html, outlook, smtp, interop

I have a very confusing problem while sending E-Mails via Interop out of a external .NET Application.

When I send a HTML-Mail via **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem.Send()** the mail is completly different displayed after I watch the Mail in Outlook (send item or recieved item). When I send the same html-content via **System.Net.Mail.MailMessage**, Outlooks displays the mail correct.

But when I look at the html-content in outlook, both are nearly the same.
So it looks like outlook is implementing some "flag" into the mail when I send it via Interop. So... does anyone know if there is chance to send a Mail via Outlook in some "save-way" regarding the html-display in outlook.

regards,

Comment: *nearly* the same isn't the same. And the email clients are rather picky about  the HTML they get fed and how they process that. And outlook is likely to optimize for its self. Without an example it is hard to tell what changed.

Comment: With @rene on this one, nearly the same isn't the same. Emails may seem small fry compared to websites but email clients are horrible creatures with weird ways. I'd recommend you test your email in mailchimp and use litmus to view it in the many email clients and devices.

Comment: The only difference is the encoding which is missing in the outlook Code-Block